# Which daemon is a lightning node running?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

To run a lightning node we can use 3 different daemons : 
 - c-lightning 
 - eclair 
 - LND

Is there a way to understand which daemon is a specific peer running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the lightning network protocol there is no direct means to detect which implementation is used by another node.

However you could use indirect hints for example the standard `cltv deltas` or channel `fees` are different for the various implementations. That being said I could obviously run clightning with the default config of lnd.

Even if there was a way (like the `user-agent` header of http) nodes could easily spoof such a header.

On a side note: just to be clear there is currently a forth implementation that is said to be mainnet ready called `Ptarmigan`. Also `electrum` is short of being ready for mainnet.